# UDP port 0.0.0.0

Tags: udp, ip-address

I have a system that is running on windows. 
I have in that system a process that waits for another process on the same machine for a udp message. The message itself is not important (garbage), but the important thing is that I got the event of the message itself.

The problem is that it seems that I get from another local program a UDP message and I don't know from where. I added information about the sender in the recieved UDP message. I see that I get message from valid local port but also from the addres 0.0.0.0 .

I can't understand the 0.0.0.0 . Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` isn't a port, it's an address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a udp message and using async type, when reading messages that arrive from the other program I can't know when stop reading, when I get reading the message and I get 0.0.0.0 it means I read everything from the UDP buffer from OS.

Answer (score 1):

A computer without an assigned IP address could send such packet, even across the network - see e.g. a similar mechanism in DHCP, where the [DHCP discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhcp#DHCP_discovery) packet is sent with source address of 0.0.0.0

On a local computer, could this be that the packet is sent (and received) on an interface that is up but without an IP address?

Also, this can mean "broadcast" - [if this article on e2](http://everything2.com/title/0.0.0.0) is correct, it is a deprecated method of making a broadcast packet, but apparently it was never removed.